# IIS / Application Pool Keep Recycling Every Minute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

My IIS / Apppool are behaving very weird. They keep recycling for almost every minute or even less. I suppose there is a memory leak somewhere.

The private byte: 137.756,00 (137 MB)
Virtual byte: 9.394.648,00 (9.39 GB????)

I only run about 2 websites. This is definitely not normal.

How can I fix this? Do I need to reinstall? I have tried to defrag my PC, but it did not help. I suppose that was because the memories are still being pointed by the application.

I tried to delete all my websites then deployed my application again, but it was not helping.

I remember that I force quit the "W something" process which was downloading some files from external source (trusted source). My web application was downloading through that "W something process" (I cant remember the name).

I force quit about 4-5 times, then this happens. What should I do to fix this?

---

**Update**

I tried reinstalled the IIS, but the problem is still around. When the request comes from my browser, I check the process worker:

> Virtual Byte = 9.394.648,00

After just starting the app pool. If I doing some debugging in my Visual Studio using IIS Express, there is nothing wrong. There is no recycling and the application runs well.

Is there a way to reset IIS / App Pool process which hold the Virtual Byte (9 GB) to 0? I read a lot about to find some memory leak and something, but in my case it is not. I did something before which made the App Pool keep holding the 9GB virtual bytes even after the app pool recycle, it still hold 9GB virtual bytes!

So I need to know a way like clearing / cleaning / uninstalling / freeing those data hold by the Application Pool.

---

**Update**

I found this error in event viewer:

> A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The
>   process id was '5832'. The data field contains the error number.

Comment: Sounds like you diagnosed the problem in the first line of your question. Fix the application.

Comment: Learn how to use a memory profiler or how to analyze dumps, and then you see how memory usage goes that high. The virtual memory usage is already a red flag and you must fix that. If you don't have the skills, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my application, if the application hosted in external server, it works fine. The problem only occurs in my local server. Give me some reference of how to clean the memory, or maybe restoring the IIS / App Pool to default like newly installed. Which is better